# Virtualbox 5 cannot access USB devices on Dell XPS 13 9343

Tags: usb, virtualbox, dell

having an annying issue with my VirtualBox 5 under Ubuntu 15.04, trying to run a Win8.1 VM.

I cannot access any USB devices, nor does the virtualbox interface show that I have any installed. Googling the problem lead me to try a few things, none of which had any effect.

- Adding my user to the virtualbox group within ubuntu `sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a $USE`
- installing the latest VB (rather than the Ubuntu repo version)
- installing the latest guest additions

The laptop is very new and possibly down to poor driver support. But is there anything else I can try in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by the VirtualBox forums thanks to user mpack!

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=69525&p=331585#p331585

1. Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
2. Looks for 'Extension Pack' and match to your version
3. Install it, done!